# Why doesn't my function work when the argument is a changing DOM variable?

Tags: javascript

The first variable needs to be DOM as you can see is commented out.
It works when i manually set the productCode variable like below.

```
let productCode = '95232' //document.getElementById('pCode').value;
let results = document.getElementById('results');

const fetchData = async  (productCode) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${productCode}`);
    const data = await response.json()
    let brand = data.brand;
    let img = data.imageSrc;
    let name = data.name;
    let scale = data.scale;
    let stock = data.stock;
    let style = data.style;
    let price = data.price;

    results.innerHTML = `
    <div>
        <img src=${img} width='200px'>
        <p>${brand} ${scale} ${name} </p>
        <p>${price}</p> 
        <p>${stock}</p>
        <p>${style}</p>
    `
  }
```

When using DOM it errors 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Edit:
The html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='pCode'>Product Code?</input>
    <button type="button" onclick="fetchData(productCode)">Click</button>
    <div id='results'> </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `pCode` element you are trying to use?

Comment: updated the main post

Comment: And what value does it have when you get the error?

Comment: Is `response` JSON? I would try consoling that.

Comment: it doesn't have one, looking in chrome dev tools it tries to reach localhost/3000/
not even undefined - if i remove the .value it instead tries to reach http://localhost:3000/[object%20HTMLInputElement]

Comment: If `response` is not JSON, or has no value (maybe?), I don't believe `response.json()` will work.

Comment: When i `console.log(response)` it returns: `{type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:3000/', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}`

however everything works fine when i manually set productCode variable to a string
just not when retrieving from DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I had to put the DOM call inside of the function like so:

```
let productCode
const results = document.getElementById('results');

const fetchData = async  (productCode) => {
    productCode = document.getElementById('pCode').value;
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${productCode}`);
    const data = await response.json()
```